# FOSCommentBundle Custom comment sorting

Tags: php, symfony, foscommentbundle

I need to implement the custom comment sorting based on the comment score , i have gone through  [14-customizing_tree_sorting.md](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/14-customizing_tree_sorting.md)
The `services:` in `my app/config.yml`  as follows

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
     demoBundle.comment.sorter.score:
        class: DemoBundle\Bundle\Sorting\CommentOrderSorting
        tags:
            - { name: fos_comment.sorter, alias: score }
```

Here the overridden methods of `SortingInterfac`  are not being called in my custom class `CommentOrderSorting` where i need to implement my logic

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should also create config with your custom sorter:

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_comment:
    service:
        sorting:
            default: score
```

Comment: Thanks @malcolm , I really could not figure out the linking but now i did and it works as expected